# whats the difference between c compiler and c++ compiler of microsoft c/c++ compiler?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

1. I could compile the void main() as c++ source file with microsoft c/c++ compiler 14.00 (integrated with visual studio 2005).So does it means that the compiler does not conform to the c++ standard on the main function prototype?
2. Is the microsoft c/c++ compiler only one compiler,that is,it is only one c++ compiler?Because C source file could be compiled as C++ source file,so its no need to develop the c compiler anymore?

   thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I could compile the `void main()`

The valid signatures of main are:

```
int main(void); // no parameters 
int main(int, char **); // parameterized
```

Everything else is not standard. The standard does allow an implementation to allow alternate signatures of `main()`.

> Is the microsoft c/c++ compiler only one compiler,that is,it is only one c++ compiler?

Yes, it is one executable (`cl.exe`). However, it can work either as a C compiler or a C++ compiler. The default is C++ compiler mode. You can change this by going into Project Properties > C/C++ > Advanced (`/TP` or `/TC`)

Comment: It also infers a default from the file extension (.c or .cpp/.cxx)

Comment: The C++ standard explicitly forbids any definition of `main` not returning `int`.